# NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, mapping

I'm begining my adventure with nHibernate and I have a problem.

My code:
Model/Project.cs

```
namespace entity1.Model
{
    public class Project
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model/Project.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" namespace="entity1.Model" assembly="entity1.Model">
  <class name="entity1.Model.Project, entity1.Model" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" column="prj_id"></id>
    <property name="Name" column="prj_name" />
    <property name="Description" column="prj_description" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Web.config

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=(local);initial catalog=todo;Integrated Security=True</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <mapping assembly="entity1.Model"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Test.aspx.cs

```
Project project = new Project();
// [...]
Configuration c = new Configuration();
c.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());

ISessionFactory factory = c.BuildSessionFactory();
using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession()) {
    using(ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction()){
        session.Save(project);
        transaction.Commit();
}
```

And exception:
No persister for: entity1.Model.Project

What is wrong?

I'm realy thank for everyone help.
Sorry for my english. It's not too good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your assembly is called `entity1.Model`?
I think this is just the namespace and the assembly is `entity1` right?

If you are not sure look into properties of your project.

And then change it within your web.config

```
<mapping assembly="entity1"/>
```

and mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" namespace="entity1.Model" assembly="entity1">
```

and you might be missing the call `c.Configure()` to load the xml config.

Comment: I checked assembly in project propertities. There is assembly: entity1. Main namespace: entity1.

Next I set namespace and assembly in mapping file and in web.config for namespace="entity1.Model" and assembly="entity1"

Unfortunetly it's wrong too.

Comment: and you might be missing the call `configuration.Configure()`